# "Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'." when using spinner.show().then()

Tags: angular9

From the docomuntation of ngx-Spinner said in FEAUTERS: "show()/hide() methods return promise",
but in my Project in intellij:

this.spinner.show() returns void.

ane therefore when im trying to do this:

```
onCheckOut() {
    this.spinner.show().then(p => {
      this.cartService.CheckoutFromCart(1);
    });
  }
```

im getting the : ERROR in src/app/components/checkout/checkout.component.ts:33:25 - error TS2339: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'.

```
33     this.spinner.show().then(p => {
```

**how i make it work?**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the documentation is wrong. When I look at the [code](https://github.com/Napster2210/ngx-spinner/blob/master/projects/ngx-spinner/src/lib/ngx-spinner.service.ts#L34), it does not return a promise:

```
show(name: string = PRIMARY_SPINNER, spinner?: Spinner) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const showPromise = new Promise((resolve, _reject) => {
        if (spinner && Object.keys(spinner).length) {
          spinner['name'] = name;
          this.spinnerObservable.next(new NgxSpinner({ ...spinner, show: true }));
          resolve(true);
        } else {
          this.spinnerObservable.next(new NgxSpinner({ name, show: true }));
          resolve(true);
        }
      });
      return showPromise;
    }, 10);
  }
```

Not sure if this was done on purpose or not, but you could raise an issue on Github.

The only way to achieve your solution would be to use the `getSpinner` method of the service:

```
const spinnerName = "my-spinner";
this.spinner.show(spinnerName);
this.spinner.getSpinner(spinnerName)
  .pipe(
     first(({show}) => !!show)
  )
  .subscribe(() => {
     this.cartService.CheckoutFromCart(1);
  }
);
```

Comment: ive copy it and got an error:

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ngx-spinner/lib/ngx-spinner.enum' in 'D:\My Projects\...'`


**i was import :**




import { NgxSpinnerService } from 'ngx-spinner';
import {PRIMARY_SPINNER} from 'ngx-spinner/lib/ngx-spinner.enum';
import {first} from 'rxjs/operators';

Comment: You are right, I would have thought that they export the name, but they don't. So the best way is to give a custom name to your spinner, see my edited answer.